# Converting coordinates Points to Slope Intercept Form?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Write the equation of the plane in intercept
form and find the points where it intersects the coordinate
axes.
 $4x + 5y − 6z = 60.$

Is there a way to algebraically using y = mx+b to convert this to this form?
I am confused as to how to convert this since this has z coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intercept form is $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$ from which the intercepts can be read off as $(a,0,0)$, etc.

In your case, dividing through by $60$ will get the needed $1$ on the right hand side.

Comment: So then you reduce and get x/15+y/12-z/10=1. The denominators are your intercepts.

Comment: @LittleJon Basically yes, but be careful of the sign of the $z$-intercept.